# Number Theory Primes and Rationals

Tags: number-theory

**Question**: Show that if the square of a rational number is an integer, than the rational number itself is an integer. Suppose the rational number is of the form $(\frac{m}{n})$, I have deduced that if $n^2$ divides  $m^2$ then $n$ divides $m^2$. The hint in my textbook says to use the prime factorization theorem but I am unsure how. I know that the divisors of $m$ are contained within some multiple of its prime divisors of the form $m=p_1^{n_1},...p_j^{n_j}$ where the $n_i$ are the powers of p. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may assume that $\frac mn$ is in shortest terms, i.e., $m,n$ have no common factor. But if $p $ is a prime with $p\mid n$ then $p\mid n^2$, $p\mid m^2$, hence $p\mid m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why can I assume that they are in the shortest terms though?

Comment: If not, just cancel the common factor.